# How to display a line in a listbox depending on the date value of the previous and next binded items?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a listbox with binded items. The items come from a collection, and have a date as a property.

I would like to display a line between two items of the listbox if the difference between their date is superior to 12 hours.

I don't know how to handle the fact that the code should look at 2 items in the collection and compare the values to display or not display the line.

I am a beginner so details will be apreciated :)
Many thanks for your help.
Best,
Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't have the ability to see what the next item is directly from XAML, so what you can do, is to calculate it in code, and insert a different element that denotes there to be a line.

Then you can use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector) to allowing you to have different data-templates based on a condition (like a boolean "IsLine").

Comment: ok thanks :) That's what I have done so far but it seems to me it was not a efficient way :) Thank you.